# How to make the slider move right and left alternatively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

The slider i have is  moving from to left side automatically and once it reaches it moves the first slider and then it repeats.

All i wanted to do is to make the slider right to left and then to left to right alternatively.

How can i do this ?

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLffv/).

**Here is the css**

```
#slideshow {
position: relative;
width: 640px;
height: 310px;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin: 0 auto 2em;
background: #FFF;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);
background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF 20%, #EEE 80%, #DDD);

-webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    }
```

As i don't have any idea in javascript i am not able to have any steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current animation keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { left: 0 }
    25%, 45%        { left: -100% }
    50%, 70%        { left: -200% }
    75%, 95%        { left: -300% }
}
```

it goes from 0 to -100% to -200% .. -300% and than back to 0.

you can change it to something like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { left: 0 }
    25%, 45%        { left: -100% }
    50%, 70%        { left: 0 }
    75%, 95%        { left: -100% }
}
```

here it will just got back and forth between 0 and -100%.

**Show more than 2 slides:**

Add classes to your slides to be able to hide and show them and created these keyframes to do so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider1 {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: visible; }
    25%, 45%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    50%, 70%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    75%, 95%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider2 {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    25%, 45%        { opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: visible; }
    50%, 70%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    75%, 95%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider3 {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    25%, 45%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    50%, 70%        { opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: visible; }
    75%, 95%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider4 {
    0%, 20%, 100%   { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    25%, 45%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    50%, 70%        { opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    75%, 95%        { opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: visible; }
}
```

now you just need to position slide 3 where 1 is and 4 where 2 is, since you have a fixed width i just used `position: relative;` and add the animation keyframes (don't forget the other prefixes)

```
#slideshow .slide_1 {
    -webkit-animation: slider1 32s infinite; 
}
#slideshow .slide_2 {
    -webkit-animation: slider2 32s infinite; 
}
#slideshow .slide_3 {
    position: relative;
    left: -1280px;
    -webkit-animation: slider3 32s infinite;   
}
#slideshow .slide_4 {
    position: relative;
    left: -1280px;
    -webkit-animation: slider4 32s infinite;   
}
```

[the finished Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLffv/2/)

Comment: I got it.. But in the your updated fiddle only two images are repeating. How can i make 5 images move like that ?

Comment: here it works with 4 slides: http://jsfiddle.net/mLffv/2/
i overlapped the slides 1 and 3, 2 and 4 so that they alternate and changed their visibility (starts at css line 351), but its a lot more complicated width 3, 5 or more slides.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. May i know what changes you have done. Could you update it in your answer please.